# translate .po file not working

Tags: wordpress

I install wordpress in english interface.

After that I install theme(alyeska) which translate to  Hebrew languege + `<html dir="rtl">`.

Inside the the theme folder there is lang\alyeska.po

I made some steps to be translation the alyeska.po:

1. I open the file alyeska.po with Poedit and change onw of the raw and I saved it as he-il.po
2. I edit the file function.php and add the line `<?php load_theme_textdomain('alyeska'); ?>` wich I don't know if it is right `('alyeska')` or need other value.
3. I open the file wp-config.php and add the line `define ('WPLANG', 'he-il');`

The translation theme not working.

What I miss here ?

Many Thx.

Answer (score 2):

try to change this

```
define ('WPLANG', 'he-il');
```

to

```
define ('WPLANG', 'he_IL');
```

also,

```
he-il.po
```

to

```
he_IL.po
```